# Create dataframe specific lists in a function

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, function

I have several datasets. I would like to create a list for each one. Is there a way to do this in some kind of function? As of now I write it one below the other, since the code is quite long I don't want to do it manually for each dataset. I want to create a datasource list for each dataset, which contains the information of the respective dataset. As of now, my code looks like this:

```
datasource = df['Data_source'].tolist()
datasource1 = df1['Data_source'].tolist()
datasource2 = df2['Data_source'].tolist()
datasource3 = df3['Data_source'].tolist()
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are your `dfs` constructed in the first place? Probably wise to put them in a container at the start. E.g. in a list: `dfs = [df, df1]`, or a dictionary. E.g. once you have a list like that, you could just do: `datasources = [df['Data_source'].tolist() for df in dfs]`.

Comment: This works so far but two steps later it falls on my feet as I can't access it as I wanted....